# My aggregator's parent is also a child and that seems ok to Maven

Tags: maven, maven-3

EDIT: The answer to the question is "that's impossible, you've either found a bug in Maven or have misunderstood something".

In my case it was the latter.

Both X and X/EXTRA uses relative path to inherit from R (X uses ../R and X/EXTRA uses ../../R). So there is no cycle in fact.

The structure in real life is much more complicated and I was trying to narrow it down to a simple example.

I've adjusted the structure (moved to R/EXTRA) and achieved the goal of that team by configuring to skip deployment in the maven-deploy-plugin.

I can't delete this question anymore but hopefully this clarifies things a bit...

---

How is it possible that a maven aggregator module X can inherit from a parent R and yet still contain that parent in its list of aggregated modules?

Elaborate example:

Project R is a root (no parent) which aggregate modules A,B with:

```
<modules>
  <module>A<module>
  <module>B<module>
</modules>
```

Project X was added alongside R, declares R as its parent where it inherits stuff from AND has R as a child module being aggregated. So directory structure looks like:

```
R/
R/A
R/B
X/
X/EXTRA
```

And X has:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>id.of.Xgroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>X</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../X</relativePath>
    </parent>
...
    <modules>
        <module>../X</module>
        <module>../EXTRA</module>
```

This working fine for me (Maven 3.3.9) and I can see that X inherits properly from R as it uses a property (jacoco version) that is specified only in R. It also causes everything to be build (order is R,A,B,EXTRA,X and EXTRA uses A/B as a dependency) so aggregation seems fine as well.

I just want to know the reason why this is allowed. Is this by design and absolutely safe (no circular conflicts may arise) and how/why is this guaranteed to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since R does not have dependency back to the X, there is no cyclic dependency currently. (But still a risky and bad design)

Having R as a module in X is not optimal solution in this case, I would recommend removing it. (After removing, adding X to R as module would be more suitable. If you don't want to do this try the below recomendation)

If the reason of X having R as module is, when you execute a certain plugin(or maven command) on X that you want it to execute on R also; I would recommend creating another aggregator that has X and R as modules, execute this mentioned plugin on this newly created aggregator.

Comment: So, currently X has a profile to activate jacoco and a child module X/EXTRA which has "developer testing tools" for working with R. This is so that we can work with test code for R locally but X never gets released (a release is performed from R). I will report back after applying your idea to see if there's something that no longer works with the new structure.

Comment: Hi, while implementing the change I realised that I misunderstood the structure. The "EXTRA" project under X actually has R as its parent (using relative path)! The goal was to release R+contents without including "EXTRA". I have moved it to the proper place and configure "skip" in maven-deploy-plugin. Thanks for your reply but I'll delete this question as it was wrong. When changing EXTRA to belong to X maven would actually complain that there is an aggregation cycle, so the answer to my question is really "this is not possible; either you've misunderstood something or found a bug!"...

Comment: @Alexandros I really got lost on this topic (I was concentrated when I wrote the answer but It seem too complicated right now), but as long as you solved your problem it is ok.

Comment: It's a bit confusing (I misunderstood as well and I was looking at it). I'll delete it, it's worthless...